# PHP - strstr() doesn't work well with MySql

Tags: php, strstr

I have these tables in my DB:

TABLE A:

```
id | haystack
-------------
1  | 682,401
2  | 351
```

TABLE B:

```
id | needle
-------------
1  | 352
2  | 682
3  | 978
```

All I want to do is to check if a haystack from table A contain any needle from table B. I did this code in PHP:

```
$res_A = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table_A');
while($row_A = mysql_fetch_array($res_A)){
    $res_B = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table_B');
    while($row_B = mysql_fetch_array($res_A)){
        if(strlen(strstr($row_A['haystack'], $row_B['needle']) > 0)){
            echo 'I found this needle: '.$row_B['needle'].' in this haystack: '.$row_A['haystack'].'<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

But, it doesn't work. I tried to figure it out all day, but no chance. I need to mention that the haystack and needle columns are Varchars.

Can you help me with this situation?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What happened? What did you expect?

Comment: For one, using a `strstr` is not a good idea unless you're always going to have 3 numbers. (what if needle contains 52 but haystack has 252?) Also, try using the [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) method on the haystack, then using [`in_array`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) with the needle.

Comment: I was expecting to see the table_a.id who contain table_b.needle in table_a.haystack (I hope I'm clear). Yes, it seems strstr is not a good idea, so I used sql instead, as many suggested. It's much easier and faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you keep it all on the SQL server? Much easier and faster..

`SELECT * from hay, needle WHERE hay.haystack LIKE CONCAT('%',needle.needle,'%');`

Comment: Easy as pie! Thank you, this is the solution I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Notice your Parenthesis placement on `strlen(strstr($row_A['haystack'], $row_B['needle']) > 0)`

Try: `if(strlen(strstr($row_A['haystack'], $row_B['needle'])) > 0)`

You are including the `> 0` in the call to `strlen`

Comment: This answer addresses the problem with your code as it stands. However, as many others suggested, I also recommend using a query to speed up processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$res_A = mysql_query('SELECT haystack FROM table_A');
while($row_A = mysql_fetch_array($res_A)){
    $res_B = mysql_query("SELECT needle FROM table_B WHERE needle = '" . $row_A['haystack'] . "'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($res_B) > 0) {  
            echo 'I found this needle: '.$row_B['needle'].' in this haystack: '.$row_A['haystack'].'<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Besides the fact that `needle` doesn't has to be equal `haystack` (so you should use `LIKE`) you will run into the problem Brad Christie allready mentioned in his comment to the question. Use `explode()` on the string and check with `in_array()`.